# Click speech bubble to display list items in order - Not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a list in my HTML with a number of quotes. I have also got a div called "speech" which is styled to look like a speech bubble.

When the program is run the first quote is displayed in the bubble and when it is clicked it skips through the list of quotes.

My issue is that in IE8 nothing is displayed in the bubble and I cannot work out why. Can someone tell me whether I am doing something wrong, or advise me on how to do a better.

Here is the list...

```
<ul class="facts">
        <li>
            <span>What goes ho-ho whoosh, ho-ho whoosh?<br/>Santa caught in a revolving door.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Whats white and goes up? <br/> A confused snowflake.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Which Christmas carols do parents like best? <br/> Silent Night.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>How did the snowman get to school?<br/>On his icicle.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>What do you call a three-legged donkey?<br/> A wonkey.</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the script...

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
rnditem : function(l) {
    var a = [],
        current = jQuery(this).html().trim(),
        index,
        next;

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(l, function(item) {
        a.push(jQuery(item).html()
               jQuery.trim();
   });

   index = a.indexOf(current) + 1;
   if (index < 0 ||  index >= l.length) {
       index = 0;
   }

   next = (l.eq(index).html());

   jQuery(this).html(next);

  return this;
   }
});

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {


var list = jQuery(".facts").find("li");

jQuery(document.body).on('click','.speech', function () {

jQuery(this).rnditem(list);
});

jQuery(".speech").trigger("click");


});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S79qp/425/

Comment: Why is the fiddle and the code here different?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Fiddle, I see different code than what is posted above.

The lines below

```
current = jQuery(this).html().trim(),
```

and

```
a.push(jQuery(item).html().trim());
```

would throw an error that would be something like

> Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'

because IE8 does not have trim built in, so use [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: Sorry wrong one. I have changed it now so it should match up. Where exactly would I put "jQuery"? @Epascarello

Comment: Did you look at the jQuery trim doc that I linked too? Follow the example.